# Create a 'dummy' URL path for frontend pictures rendering

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have application with DjangoRestFramework for backend and Vue.js for frontend.
My user can upload pictures and they are stored in an `uploaded_media` file.

Therefore I added `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to my urlpatterns.

But since it is a Single Page Application, I added `re_path(r"^.*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point"),` in my `urlpatterns` for everything to be redirected to my `index.html`.

My issue is since my pictures URL is fetched in this format: `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/my_pic.jpg"`, it can't be rendered frontend because it's redirected to my `entry-point`.

So I made a 'dummy' URL path (`path('media/', DummyView.as_view())`) pointing to a dummy View:

```
class DummyView(TemplateView):
    pass
```

And it works... just for the first picture. I am doing it right and missing something or I am going to the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I find a better way than creating a 'dummy' view, I just change my `entry-point` URL this way:

```
re_path(r"^(?!media).*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")
```

So everything except the URL starting with 'media' is redirected to the `entry-point`